# Does $P(X+Y=k | Y = k) = P(X = 0)$ hold true?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, random-functions

Given two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$. Does the statement

$P( X + Y = k | Y = k) = P(X = 0)$

hold true always?

My logic is

$P( X + Y = k | Y = k) 
\\= \frac{P(X + Y = k  \cap Y = k)}{P(Y=k)} 
\\= \frac{P(X+k= k \cap Y=k)}{P(Y=k)} 
\\= \frac{P(X=0 \cap Y =k)}{P(Y=k)} 
\\= \frac{P(X=0)P( Y =k)}{P(Y=k)} 
\\= P(X=0) $

but I'm not sure if the second and third line are correct.

Comment: This is fine unless $Y=k$ has probability zero. In words, if you know $Y=k$ is true and this tells you nothing about $X$, then knowledge of $Y+X = k$ is equivalent to $X=0$

Comment: Even simpler is just substituting within the probability: $P(X+Y = k \ | \ Y = k) = P(X+k = k) = P(X = 0)$. As long as the point in the comment above holds ($Y = k$ has some probability).